# Dice marked in Japanese

Tags: dice

I am trying to find d&d dice sets marked with Japanese characters.  I've only been able to find d10 sets. Is there any place I can buy complete sets (d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, d20)?

Comment: Two reasons: 1) Japanese RPGs tend to almost always be d6 based (I'm surprised you found d10s). 2) Using arabic numerals is very common in Japan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Q Workshop](http://www.q-workshop.com/) manufactures some [Japanese dice sets](http://q-workshop.com/c/299/japanese.html). Amazon has their [red and white set for sale](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008X9YFGU).

[image]

Comment: This is much clearer after the edit, thank you! Have a +1.

Answer (score 15):

Have a look at: [d6](http://www.thegamestore.com/Japanese_Kanji_Dice_p/19-10365.htm), or [d6/d10](http://stores.ebay.com/G2-Collectibles-and-Hobbies/_i.html?_nkw=Kanji%20dice%20-auction).  However, you could always adapt [this method](https://web.archive.org/web/20120424183401/http://www.dicecreator.com/2010/05/20/open-source-dice-making) of making the dice themselves. [This site](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~armiller/japanese/kanjinumbers.htm) amongst others can give you the kanji for the numbers.

The following sites do custom dice, so you can send them your kanji et voila.

- [Crystal Caste](http://www.crystalcaste.com/custom.htm)
- [Chessex](http://www.chessex.com/Dice/Custom_Dice_Home.htm)
- [Game Station](http://customdice.com/pricing.php)
- [Q Workshop](http://q-workshop.com/help_more.php?topic=customdice&lang=EN&sell_type=DETAL&currency=EUR)

Credit goes to [AceCalhoon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/77/acecalhoon) in a [meta thread on swag](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/what-rpg-specific-swag-would-you-like)...

Comment: +1 for the make-your-own link, but still hoping for a retail source of ready-to-use dice

Comment: @shimonyk: I can sympathise and best of luck.  If you do find some, please let us know.

Comment: Unfortunately the make-your-own-dice link has expired.  Any chance you know where to find them these days?

Comment: @Joe: I am afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

[Koplow Games](http://www.koplowgames.com/) makes d10s, as you've noted. They also make d6s, numbered from 1-6 or 7-12. (You can find them on pages 70 and 71 of the linked catalog. The d10s are on page 75.) Your local game store should be able to order them. There are no d4s, d8s, d12s or d20s.